# How to obfuscate a quick link to an external site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to hide, obfuscate or redirect a URL that points to an external site from quick links?

We send our users to a link that contains the site password in clear text, similar to this:

`https://website.com/?user=username&pw=password`

We want to hide those credentials for hopefully obvious reasons.

In the olden days of our PHP-based intranet, we would just link users to an internal PHP page, and the PHP page would redirect them to the above link. The third-party site redirects the request as well, so users never see the actual URL.

Is there a way to do this in SharePoint?

**Caveat:** I am a site owner but not a SharePoint administrator.

Comment: You send users to a link that contains the site password in clear text, similar to this:

https://website.com/?user=username&pw=password  Can you provide some screenshots for this? Where is this link generated?

Comment: I don't know what good a screenshot would do. The link is generated by the company that runs the third-party website. We pay for an enterprise license to use their site (it is a specialized searchable database), and authenticate our employees using the credentials in the URL.